# Divergence Theorem Problem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f,g:R^3\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ be $C^1$, let $\Omega=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2=1, z\geq 0\}$, $\Lambda=\{(x,y,z):0<x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1, z\geq 0\}$ and $T=\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2=1, z=0\}$. Show that $|\int\int_{\Omega}\nabla f\times\nabla g\cdot\hat{n}dS|\leq\pi\ \text{sup}_{t\in T}\{|f(t)\nabla g(t)|+|g(t)\nabla f(t)|\}$

My initial thought was since for vectors $A,B,C$ we have $\nabla\cdot(A\times B)=B\cdot(\nabla\times\nabla A)-A\cdot(\nabla\times\nabla B)$, so using the divergence theorem, and substituting $A=\nabla f$ and $B=\nabla g$, we get $\int\int_{\Omega}\nabla f\times\nabla g\cdot\hat{n}dS=\int\int\int_{\Lambda}\nabla\cdot(\nabla f\times\nabla g)dV=\int\int\int_{\Lambda}0dV=0$, so the inequality would be trivial. But I think $\Lambda$ might not have the right properties for divergence theorem to hold (I know closed and bounded is sufficient, but not sure if necessary).

So instead I thought to do the same calculation above except replace $\Lambda$ with $\Lambda_a=\{(x,y,z):a\leq x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1, z\geq a\}$. Then each $\Lambda_a$ is closed and bounded and the above calculation holds (I think) for each $\Lambda_a$. This means that the only contribution $\int\int_{\Omega}\nabla f\times\nabla g\cdot\hat{n}dS$ can make is the flux through the circle $T$.

Since $|\nabla f\times\nabla g\cdot\hat{n}|=|\nabla f||\nabla g|\text{cos}(\theta_{f,g})\text{cos}\phi\leq |\nabla f||\nabla g|$, where $\phi$ is the angle between $\nabla f\times\nabla g$ and $\hat{n}$, we have $\int_{T}\nabla f\times\nabla g\cdot\hat{n}dl\leq\int_{T}|\nabla f||\nabla g|dl\leq\text{sup}_{t\in T}\{|\nabla f(t)||\nabla g(t)|\}\int_Tdl=2\pi\text{sup}_{t\in T}\{|\nabla f(t)||\nabla g(t)|\}$

This isn't the right bound, so I'm thinking there's something wrong with my approach. Does anyone have any suggestions?